# HTML/CSS_IMG and SVG layering

Tags: html, css, svg, position, layer

I need to solve issue with layering. On the background I need to have `rect`, then above it `img` and all other elements on the top, like in the example picture. I tried to use `z-index` for this.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>z-index</title>

    <style>
      svg {
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
      }

      .img-overlay-wrap img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 80px;
        z-index: 0;
      }

      .img-overlay-wrap svg {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: -1;
      }

      .front {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="img-overlay-wrap">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="300" fill="#dcd1c4"></rect>
        <g class="front">
          <text style="color: #538b01;" x="150" y="150">SVG Text</text>
          <line x1="34" y1="47" x2="279" y2="47" stroke="black" />
        </g>
      </svg>
      <img
        src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-6QFHkPCFUJE/US10_Byu7TI/AAAAAAAADm0/zRcsPaMQpp8/s1600/pink+camellia.jpg"
        height="200"
      />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Approach to put `img` in between 2 SVG-elements gave same result:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>z-index</title>

    <style>
      svg {
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
      }

      .img-overlay-wrap img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 80px;
        z-index: 0;
      }

      .img-overlay-wrap svg {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: -1;
      }

      .front {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="img-overlay-wrap">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="300" fill="#dcd1c4"></rect>
      </svg>
      <img  src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-6QFHkPCFUJE/US10_Byu7TI/AAAAAAAADm0/zRcsPaMQpp8/s1600/pink+camellia.jpg"
        height="200"
      />
      <svg>
        <text style="color: #538b01;" x="150" y="150">SVG Text</text>
        <line x1="34" y1="47" x2="279" y2="47" stroke="black" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Tried tag `use` with the attribute `xlink:href`, but also without success:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>z-index</title>

    <style>
      svg {
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
      }

      .img-overlay-wrap img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 80px;
        z-index: 0;
      }

      .img-overlay-wrap svg {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: -1;
      }

      .front {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="img-overlay-wrap">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="300" fill="#dcd1c4"></rect>
        <g class="front">
          <text style="color: #538b01;" x="150" y="150">SVG Text</text>
          <line x1="34" y1="47" x2="279" y2="47" stroke="black" />
        </g>
        <use xlink:href=".front"/>
      </svg>
      <img
        src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-6QFHkPCFUJE/US10_Byu7TI/AAAAAAAADm0/zRcsPaMQpp8/s1600/pink+camellia.jpg"
        height="200"
      />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you could either use two svg elements. One before the img with the rect in it and one after the img with the text and line in it. Or convert the html img element into an SVG image element and put it between the rect and the <g>

Comment: I tried, but with the same result (
Don't really want to make extra conversion coz usually it is useful simply use link to `img` file and there should be any other option I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

1. Put`svg` with `rect` as background
2. Put `img`
3. Put `h1`
4. Put`svg` with other elements

For all of them `z-index` should be the same.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>z-index</title>

    <style>
      svg {
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
      }

      .img-overlay-wrap img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 80px;
      }

      .img-overlay-wrap svg {
        position: absolute;

      }

      .front {
        position: absolute;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="img-overlay-wrap">
      
      <svg>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="300" fill="#dcd1c4"></rect>
      </svg>
      
      <img  src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-6QFHkPCFUJE/US10_Byu7TI/AAAAAAAADm0/zRcsPaMQpp8/s1600/pink+camellia.jpg"
        height="200"
      />
      <h1 class="front">Header</h1>
      <svg>
        <text style="color: #538b01;" x="150" y="150">SVG Text</text>
        <line x1="34" y1="47" x2="279" y2="47" stroke="black" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```